# How to search for a string from a large number of table in sql?

Tags: sql, .net, search

I have a project where more than 120 tables are present. I want to make a search box where user can input any string and i will show the formatted result based on the found data and its relative table. These tables contains thousands of data.the string can  be found in  more than 1 tables. 
like for example:

search box text : "shirt"

I will show

1.Store item with tag "shirt" from item table

2.Show comments about "shirt"   from 'comments' table

3.A list of user who have interest in 'shirt'.

4.etc ... from other found tables.

How should i proceed for it?

Comment: Seems like a horrible database design. 120 tables, and you have no idea at all where things are stored?

Comment: I used the scenario as an example. And  I know where all things are stored. I just want to show search result from multiple tables with a huge amount of data.

Comment: Perhaps nosql is the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query from all 120 tables, you may use sys.tables and query from each table. But it would not be so efficient. First, if possible it is better to do a database design or change the database design.